# Teamcity - Create git tag after successful build

Tags: git, teamcity, git-tag

How can I create a git tag after successful build in Team City?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [VCS Labeling build feature](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/VCS+Labeling) to tag successful builds in TeamCity.

Comment: can you add a tag message?

Comment: Be aware that this does not work for personal builds I case you want to use a personal build to test the settings ;)

Answer (score 1):

After each successful build from team city a new git tag is created in github repo

Follow this https://link.medium.com/5XrNt4i9f5